# Highcharter and Plotly don't work in Shiny when using htmlTemplate() page

Tags: html, r, shiny

Hoping someone can help. I am building a shiny app with an htmlTemplate page as the UI for the first time, and I'm noticing that highcharter and plotly graphs don't render on it. I'm wondering if this is a conflict between html widgets and an html page? Are there certain rules around this that I should know? I would post my code but the dashboard is very large. Currently I have the below in the "head" of my html page. Maybe these are causing the conflict?

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.0.5];htmlwidgets[1.0];plotly-binding[4.7.1.9000];bootstrap[3.3.7]</script>
  <script src="shared/json2-min.js"></script>
  <script src="shared/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>
  <script src="htmlwidgets-1.0/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
  <script src="plotly-binding-4.7.1.9000/plotly.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="shared/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. The issue was that in R, I was using Highcharter and Plotly which both have their own underlying versions of JavaScript. In my HTML file, I had loaded in a different JavaScript package. What was happening was that the version in the HTML file was overriding the versions in Highcharter and Plotly, causing them to not appear in my app when launched. I deleted the line in my HTML file that loaded JavaScript and this app now works.